# Old PHP navigation - rewriting code

Tags: php, navigation

I am changing one old app written 10 years ago in PHP. When I installed it on my computer this part, which move through pages, doesn't work well and I receive the error message:

Undefined variable: op

```
if (isset($search)){
    $sql="select * from tabella where ncomm='$search'";
    $result=mysql_db_query($db,$sql);
    $rex=mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($rex==0){
        header("location:error.html");
        exit();
    }
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
} elseif($op=="next"){
    $sqlxx="select * from tabella where id='".($idpart+1)."'";
    $resultxx=mysql_db_query($db,$sqlxx);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($resultxx);

} elseif($op=="previous"){
    $sqlxx="select * from tabella where id='".($idpart-1)."'";
    $resultxx=mysql_db_query($db,$sqlxx);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($resultxx);

} else {
    $sql="select * from tabella order by id desc limit 1";
    $result=mysql_db_query($db,$sql);
    $rex=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($rex==0){
        header("location:error.html");
        exit();
    }
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_db_query` has been deprecated in php 5.5:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future

check out [PHP: mysql_db_query - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php)

i cannot exactly say that your code will fix because i don't know complete codes and  variables you have used on that page. but it seems you have used a deprecated function.and also you have to check $op location to see where it comes.

Comment: Thank you very much for you quickly answer. I already started to change mysql_db_query as well as type of connection (PDO), but unfortunately i still not have good result.